# should i always lock the global data in multi-thread programming, why or why not?

Tags: c++, multithreading, global-variables

I'm new to multi-thread programming(actually, i'm not a fresh man in multi-threading, but i always use global data for reading and writing thread, i think it makes my code ugly and slow, i'm eager to improve my skill)

and i'm now developing a forwarder server using c++, for simplify the question, we suppose there are only two threads, a receiving-thread and a sending-thread, and, the stupid design as usual, I have an global std::list for saving data :(

`receiving-thread` read raw data from server and wirte it into global std::list.

`sending-thread` read global std::list and send it to several clients.

i use `pthread_mutex_lock` to sync the global std::list.

the problem is that the performance of forward server is poor, global list locked when `receiving-thread` is wrting, but at that time, my `sending-thread` wanna read, so it must waiting, but i think this waiting is useless.

what should i do, i know that global is bad, but, without global, how can i sync these two threads?

i'll keep searching from SO and google.

any suggestions, guides, technology or books will be appreciated. thanks!

**EDIT**

1. for any suggestions, i wanna know why or why not, please give me the reason, thanks a lot.

Comment: You are probably holding the lock *way* too long. You need to acquire the lock, get/put the data as quickly as possible, then release the lock. Also, don't say "global data", it will only confuse you. Say "shared data", because the data is shared by threads. (Global data might be used by only one thread and shared data may not be global.)

Comment: As what Herb Sutter has greatly emphasized, always remember that sharing is bad. It will be good for you to read [his blog](http://herbsutter.com/). Also [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism) video.

Comment: @David Schwartz i'm lock it before `push_back` of `std::list`, and unlock it immediately. and for your suggestion of `shared-data`, i think i'm already confused with `global` and `shared`, cus' i always use truely `global` things for threads in c++. i don't understand how can `shared data` may not be global.

Comment: For things as this you'd usually use double or even triple buffering so that each thread has its own list to work on. The interchange only happens when the sender's current list is empty and should not take more than a pointer swap, which should on most architectures be achievable with a lockless atomic. edit: actually, splitting threads based on sender/receiver is often not an optimal approach (It seems like an external requirement for you but just keep in mind it isn't necessarily best practice).

Comment: @Mark Garcia thanks, i will read it.

Comment: @KillianDS i got your point, i've never heard about this, thanks and i'll try it.

Comment: @billhoo: If your code only holds the lock for an instant, then the chances of either thread waiting are very low, and if they do, it will only be for the instant it takes the other thread to release the lock. If you're seeing performance problems from the lock, you must be doing too much work while holding it. Profile your code. And learn how to share data properly between threads.

Comment: I garee with the others - it sounds to me like you may be copying bulk data inside the lock instead of pointers/smart_ptrs.

Comment: @David Schwartz i think i really should learn how to share data properly, and as Mark Garcia quoted, share is bad, i'll learn it at the same time. thanks for helping!

Comment: @KillianDS i noticed your edit, sender/receiver is not a best practice, i'm keeping in mind now, but why? maybe i can not understand the reason right now, but i wanna know it, for later review. thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes:

1. Please provide more complete examples: http://sscce.org/

Answers:

1. Yes, you should synchronize access to shared data.

   - NOTE: this makes assumptions about std::list implementation - which may or may not apply to your case - but since this assumptions is valid for some implementation you cannot assume your implementation must be thread safe without some explicit guarantee
   - Consider the snippet:

     ```
     std::list g_list;

     void thread1()
     {
         while( /*input ok*/ )
         {
             /*read input*/
             g_list.push_back( /*something*/ );
         }
     }

     void thread2()
     {
         while( /*something*/ )
         {
             /*pop from list*/
             data x = g_list.front();
             g_list.pop_front();
         }
     }
     ```
   - say for example list has 1 element in it
   - std::list::push_back() must do:

     - allocate space (many CPU instructions)
     - copy data into new space (many CPU instructions)
     - update previous element (if it exists) to point to new element
     - set std::list::_size
   - std::list::pop_front() must do:

     - free space
     - update next element to not have previous element
     - set std::list_size
   - Now say thread 1 calls push_back() - after checking that there is an element (check on size) - it continues to update this element - but right after this - before it gets a chance to update the element - thread 2 could be running pop_front - and be busy freeing the memory for the first element - which could result then in thread 1 causing a segmentation fault - or even memory corruption. Similarly updates to size could result in push_back winning over pop_front's update - and then you have size 2 when you only have 1 element.
2. Do not use pthread_* in C++ unless you really know what your doing - use std::thread (c++11) or boost::thread - or wrap pthread_* in a class by yourself - because if you don't consider exceptions you will end up with deadlocks
3. You cannot get past some form of synchronization in this specific example - but you could optimize synchronization

   1. Don't copy the data itself into and out of the std::list - copy a pointer to the data into and out of the list
   2. Only lock while your actually accessing the std::list - but don't make this mistake:

      ```
      {
          // lock
          size_t i = g_list.size();
          // unlock
          if ( i )
          {
              // lock
              // work with g_list ...
              // unlock
          }
      }
      ```
4. A more appropriate pattern here would be a message queue - you can implement one with a mutex, a list and a condition variable. Here are some implementations you can look at:

   - http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Notification.html
   - http://gnodebian.blogspot.com.es/2013/07/a-thread-safe-asynchronous-queue-in-c11.html
   - http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_message_queue_3_01_t_01_4.html
   - google for more
5. There is also the option of atomic containers, look at:

   - http://calumgrant.net/atomic/ - not sure if this is backed by actual atomic storage (as opposed to just using synchronization behind an interface)
   - google for more
6. You could also go for an asynchronous approach with boost::asio - though your case should be quite fast if done right.